# Spring amqp convert different json messagetypes to Java objects in 1 queue?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amqp

Normally i see examples where specific messages are put in 1 queue and converted to Java objects. Currently I would like to have 1 event queue that can contain multiple types of events and have listeners for specific types of these events. Is there a way to have multiple event types in 1 queue and have separate message listeners on that same queue?

Comment: Why you can't use separate queues with separate listeners for each type? It's more convenient and what for RabbitMQ typically used.

Answer (score 0):

In short - yes you can.

You can create multiple listeners for one queue. In each listener you will try to parse specific type JSON of event from message. If parser can't parse this message - it means that this message need to be send to other listener. In this case parser will throw exception, and you should reject this message back to queue (by throwing any exception and if `defaultRequeuRejected` is not changed and by default is true). The same approach for other listeners per each event type.
But this is overkill. Because when you reject message back to queue it goes to other free listener randomly. It means, that message can return back to the same listener again.

The right approach in this case - is to use one listener, and trying to parse message for different types. If parser can't parse this type - catch exception and try other. This approach will reduce redundant message discards.

But for me, the best way - is to use different queues for each type, with different listeners. For convenience you can group them by one topic. This id for RabbitMQ was designed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My use case is that my application has 1 event queue with different kind of messages in it. For example AccountCreatedEvent, AccountDeletedEvent, RedrawMoneyEvent etc.. I would like to hook up different applications to the event queue so these applications can get notified when and event has triggerd and per application deal with these events if they need it. So more or less it is a eventbus across different applications.